# Mediawiki blank all pages per namespace. I want to blank all User_talk pages

Tags: mediawiki

I want to know if there is a way to blank all user_talk pages enmass. Not delete them, just blank them.  I don't know how to write bots, so I'm really asking if there is an extension or pre written bot for this. Thank you

Comment: Nearly every bot should be capable of doing this. Have you checked any of them?

Comment: I don't understand how to use them and was looking for an easy way out.I will go research bots now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple SQL to do this, just look into the page table, for my installation the namespace value for User talk: is 3, so I could just delete all pages with namespace=3.

**Deleting the row from the database, will leave the page as blank (not created)**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [AWB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAutoWikiBrowser).  You can easy have it build a list based on a names space and then use a simple [ReGeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) replace such as: Search: `(.*)*` Replace with: (empty space).